# Bootstrap > carousel display problem in carousel-item

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a display problem with my carousel-items.
I jave 2 elements in carousel-items (an image and a text) which should be displayed side by side but the image is centered and I REALLY don't know why...

```
<!-- Added code -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Pour nos ainés</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<!-- End added code -->
And
 
<body>
        <header class="bg-success">
            <div id="monCarrousel" class="carousel carousel-dark slide pointer-event d-none d-md-block"
                data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#monCarrousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
                        aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#monCarrousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"
                        class=""></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#monCarrousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3" class=""
                        aria-current="true"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <!-- si on veut intervalle en ms : data-bs-interval="3000-->
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="img-fluid m-3" width="200px" height="200px" src="img/header1.png" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
                                <h1>Nous sommes à leurs côtés</h1>
                                <p class="text-start">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur
                                    voluptate fugiat.
                                </p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#">Faites un don</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    <div> Another item
```

Anyone does have a pist ? I'm desesperated

Thanks per advance and sorry for my english :/

That's what I have :

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtIbX.png)

Comment: its working for me in a codepen, youy must have additional css styles not shown here.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code which is previous. I have no css and I import via min.js via :

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: I have added the image of the result that I have

Comment: I said, I entered your code (with a missing div added at the end) to codepen.io, included bootstrap css and js, and it works fine. Try it yourself. Use your browser's debugging tools to see the css that is being applied to the element.